# Facebook request in as3 sdk

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, dialog

I can't send facebook request as the popup window loads empty in firefox and gives a HTTP 500 error in iExplorer. I'm using the as3 sdk and this the code i have:

```
function gotoInvite(e:Event):void{
var sendTo:String=e.target.vstId;
var fbReq:Object=new Object;
fbReq.message='test request.';
fbReq.title='Some test';
fbReq.to=sendTo;
Facebook.ui('apprequest',fbReq,inviteResult,'popup');
}
```

I'm thinking the params aren't set corectly but i can't find a good example. I want to use the request dialog for just 1 id... Please help

Comment: Who ever rated my question -1 why didn't you post at least a comment to explain yourself...? if the answer is so obvious please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
Facebook.ui('apprequests',fbReq,inviteResult,'popup');
```